# Access Vagrant Headless VBox from Android Virtual Device on OSX Host

Tags: android, macos, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a Vagrant VirtualBox ([Scotchbox](https://box.scotch.io/)) on my Mac Mini (Yosemite) and a test server inside the box (LAMP) running a website on it. From the iOS Simular and regular browsers I can reach it well.

From my Android Virtual Device (emulator64-arm, Android 4.2.2, native browser) on the same OSX (Yosemite) host I only get unformatted text and links, no image. - see below.
 cannot inspect elements inside the virtual device so no help there. 
When I load the site using the host name site.dev as stored in etc/hosts on the host (OSX) I get nothing at all. Only by ip at least I can load a broken site.

That is with this Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "scotch/box"
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
    config.vm.hostname = "scotchbox"
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=666"] }

end
```

I changed from a private to public network to see if I could load a whole site from my Virtual Device.This is the Vagrantfile after the small tweak:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "scotch/box"
    config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
    config.vm.hostname = "scotchbox"
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=666"] }

end
```

When I ran `vagrant reload` with `public_network` instead of `private_network` I see

```
vagrant@127.0.0.1's password:password
==> default: Checking if box 'scotch/box' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Available bridged network interfaces:
1) en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)
2) en2: Thunderbolt 1
3) en0: Ethernet
4) bridge0
5) p2p0
6) awdl0
==> default: When choosing an interface, it is usually the one that is
==> default: being used to connect to the internet.
    default: Which interface should the network bridge to? 1
```

I picked one being on a wireless network.. Not sure if that was the best choice .. But then I was told:

```
NFS requires a host-only network to be created.
Please add a host-only network to the machine (with either DHCP or a
static IP) for NFS to work.
```

Any ideas why I cannot just load the site on my Virtual Device from Android Studio using the *initial* Vagrantfile setup? Localhost loaded just fine on `10.0.2.2`. How to fix this issue?

screenshot of virtual device
[image: android virtual device]

Comment: Read here that I should be able to reach the VagrantBox as both virtual boxes are on the same host http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401565/how-can-i-access-a-vagrant-guest-from-another-virtualbox-guest?rq=1

Comment: Just tried Chrome 37 on another virtual device and I still get the same page without images or layout. Just text and links.

Comment: Just on Lolipop trying to use the host name I got a connection refused so it seems my AVD is not allowed access to the Vagrant Box based website after all..

Comment: After VBox upgrade the Android Studio Virtual Device refuses to load `emulator: Failed to sync HAX vcpu context` . Seems to be it cannot run together with VBox anymore...? Perhaps I need another solution.. Like allowing others on the network to access the box and use a real Samsung Tab running Android..

Comment: After running AVD with ARM the `emulator: Failed to sync vcpu reg
emulator: Failed to sync HAX vcpu context` went away. Found an answer to that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024538/how-do-i-fix-failed-to-sync-vcpu-reg-error Now see if I can connect to the Vagrant box as is the issue in this question.

Comment: Read here Vagrant and NFS demands a private network http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html just now. With VM Ware Fusion that does not seem to be the case, but will require a license for VM Ware and the Vagrant plugin.

Comment: Seems port fowarding on a private network does not work either to access it from another network device or in my case from my AVD: http://serverfault.com/questions/545413/expose-virtual-machine-vagrant-to-local-wifi